# Do I need z scale factor?

Tags: qgis

I am making a slope raster in QGIS from DEM.
My DEM was made using WGS84 coordinates system.
Do I need to be using a z scale conversion factor ?
If so what would that be?

Comment: What are the spatial units of your DEM?

Comment: I'm not sure how I find that out. they told me it should be compatible with wgs84. And a map that was produced from it displays measurement in feet, yards.

Comment: @MappaGnosis, Can I get your contact info?